# Phonecall Database SQL Queries

Tags: sql, recursive-query, recursive-datastructures

I have been working on a database project for a phone call, here is a quick view of the diagram, callid is autoincremented in the call table, and sessionid is auto incremented in the session table, This way on a three way call the calls have the same diagram.  I have entered in fictitious data in every field except sessionstarttime and sessionend time

Using phpmyadmin,

My question:  I need to do a one query that will give me billable time for the customer aka a phonenumber.

Example phone call

A -> B from 12:00PM to 1:00PM

B -> C from 12:30PM to 1:30PM

A should be billed for 1hour

B should be billed for 1 1/2 hours (1:30 hrs)

C should be billed for 1 hour

Another Example
A -> B 12:00PM to 1:00PM
A -> C 12:30PM to 1:30PM

A should be billed for 1 1/2 hours (1:30 hrs)

B should be billed for 1hour

C should be billed for 1 hour

Here are the given data formats

```
    - <table name="Account">
      <column name="AccountID">1</column> 
      <column name="AcctHolderNum">617-100-5001</column> 
      <column name="ProviderID">1</column> 
      </table>

    <table name="call">
      <column name="callID">4</column> 
      <column name="callSender">617-719-9000</column> 
      <column name="callReceiver">617-730-8100</column> 
      <column name="callStartTime">2012-11-06 06:44:50</column> 
      <column name="callEndTime">2012-11-06 06:55:50</column> 
      <column name="sessionID">1</column> 

    - <table name="phoneNum">
      <column name="phoneNum">617-300-2000</column> 
      <column name="phoneNumFN">Nigel</column> 
      <column name="phoneNumLN">Thornberry</column> 
      <column name="PhoneAccountID">2</column> 

    - <table name="Provider">
      <column name="ProviderID">1</column> 
      <column name="ProviderName">T-Mobile</column> 
      </table>

    - <table name="session">
      <column name="sessionID">1</column> 
      <column name="sessionStartTime">2012-11-06 06:44:50</column> 
      <column name="sessionEndTime">2012-11-06 06:55:50</column>
```

Here is the ER diagram

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrh4B.jpg

Here is what I got started thinking but drown myself in confusion trying to make the one query fit every possible input in the call table

```
    FROM `call` as `call1`, `call` as `call2`, `call` as `call3`
    WHERE `call1.sessionid` = `call2.sessionid` = `call3.sessionid`
    AND <REST OF STUFF>
    UNION /* not union all, but union*/
    SELECT same as above but for three way calls
    FROM `call` as `call1`, `call` as `call2`,
    WHERE `call1.sessionid` = `call2.sessionid`
    AND <REST OF STUFF>
    UNION
    SELECT same as above but for two way calls
    FROM `call`
    WHERE <REST OF STUFF>
```

Also here are a couple of simple queries for reference

Calculates length of each call

```
    SELECT TIMEDIFF(MIN(`callStartTime`), MAX(`callEndTime`)) 
    FROM `call` GROUP BY `callID`
```

Calculates length of each session

```
    SELECT TIMEDIFF(MIN(`callStartTime`), MAX(`callEndTime`)) 
    FROM `call` GROUP BY `sessionID`
```

Minutes of calls made (note callsender) by account

```
    SELECT SUM(TIMEDIFF(`callStartTime`, `callEndTime`)) 
    FROM `call`, `Phonenum` 
    WHERE `phoneNum.phoneNum` = `call.callSender`  
    GROUP BY `phoneAccountID`
```

Minutes of calls recieved (note callreciever) by account

```
    SELECT SUM(TIMEDIFF(`callStartTime`, `callEndTime`)) 
    FROM `call`, `Phonenum` 
    WHERE `phoneNum.phoneNum` = `call.callReciever` GROUP BY `phoneAccountID`
```

Here is the xml output for the schema

```
    - <pma:structure_schemas>
    - <pma:database name="jr_Team5" collation="utf8_general_ci" charset="utf8">
      <pma:table name="Account">CREATE TABLE `Account` ( `AccountID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'AI Primary Key', `AcctHolderNum` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Account Holder''s Phone Number i.e. "617-100-5001"', `ProviderID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign Key from "ProviderID"', PRIMARY KEY (`AccountID`), KEY `AcctHolderNum` (`AcctHolderNum`), KEY `ProviderID` (`ProviderID`), CONSTRAINT `Account_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ProviderID`) REFERENCES `Provider` (`ProviderID`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;</pma:table> 
      <pma:table name="call">CREATE TABLE `call` ( `callID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'AI Primary Key', `callSender` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Phone Number of Caller', `callReceiver` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Phone Number of Reciever', `callStartTime` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'Time Call Begins', `callEndTime` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'Time Call Ends', `sessionID` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign Key from "SessionID"', PRIMARY KEY (`callID`), KEY `callSender` (`callSender`), KEY `callReceiver` (`callReceiver`), KEY `sessionID` (`sessionID`), CONSTRAINT `call_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`callSender`) REFERENCES `phoneNum` (`phoneNum`), CONSTRAINT `call_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`callReceiver`) REFERENCES `phoneNum` (`phoneNum`), CONSTRAINT `call_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`sessionID`) REFERENCES `session` (`sessionID`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=61 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;</pma:table> 
      <pma:table name="phoneNum">CREATE TABLE `phoneNum` ( `phoneNum` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Phone Number on Record', `phoneNumFN` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'First Name of Phone User', `phoneNumLN` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Last Name of Phone User', `PhoneAccountID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign Key from "AccountID"', PRIMARY KEY (`phoneNum`), KEY `PhoneAccountID` (`PhoneAccountID`), CONSTRAINT `phoneNum_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PhoneAccountID`) REFERENCES `Account` (`AccountID`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;</pma:table> 
      <pma:table name="Provider">CREATE TABLE `Provider` ( `ProviderID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'AI Primary Key', `ProviderName` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Network Provider i.e. "Verizon" or "Sprint"', PRIMARY KEY (`ProviderID`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;</pma:table> 
      <pma:table name="session">CREATE TABLE `session` ( `sessionID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'AI Primary Key', `sessionStartTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Session Begin Time', `sessionEndTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Session End Time', PRIMARY KEY (`sessionID`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;</pma:table> 
      </pma:database>
      </pma:structure_schemas>
```

Thanks for your help in advance,any help/input/direction would be appreciated let me know if you think of any other complex queries possible for this database

Fourway call data example in xml

```
    - <table name="call">
      <column name="callID">40</column> 
      <column name="callSender">617-292-1309</column> 
      <column name="callReceiver">617-300-2000</column> 
      <column name="callStartTime">2012-10-31 09:07:35</column> 
      <column name="callEndTime">2012-10-31 11:07:35</column> 
      <column name="sessionID">7</column> 
      </table>
    - <table name="call">
      <column name="callID">41</column> 
      <column name="callSender">617-300-2000</column> 
      <column name="callReceiver">617-234-1234</column> 
      <column name="callStartTime">2012-10-31 09:37:35</column> 
      <column name="callEndTime">2012-10-31 12:37:35</column> 
      <column name="sessionID">7</column> 
      </table>
    - <table name="call">
      <column name="callID">42</column> 
      <column name="callSender">617-234-1234</column> 
      <column name="callReceiver">617-200-4000</column> 
      <column name="callStartTime">2012-10-31 10:37:35</column> 
      <column name="callEndTime">2012-10-31 11:37:35</column> 
      <column name="sessionID">7</column>
```

Comment: A phone call typically has a "to" and a "from", as in your data structure.  Can you explain how you have a phone call with three parts?

Comment: Here is an example of a 4 way call, which would have three entries into the call table, all with callids auto incremented in the call table, with sessionid as a foreign key, in this case of a four way call they all have different callids, but the same sessionid

Comment: It would be good to make your question a bit more general. It is good that you have shown some effort and included background information but as a general rule of thumb it is best to avoid asking questions using the terminology defined by your problem domain specifically. In other words ' I need to do a one query that will give me billable time for the customer aka a phonenumber' should be something more like : 'given the following table definitions *blah blah blah*, how would I perform the following operation *pseudo-code or plain english*'

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two problems here.  The first is determining how much time to allot to each caller in a session.  The second is to aggregate this information.

Let me assume that all the time for a given phone number in a session is contiguous.  That is, there is no call from B--> from 12:00 to 12:15 (because C would not be contiguous).  Then you can get the timings for each user within a session:

```
select c.sessionid, c.caller,
       (max(c.EndTime) - min(c.StartTime)) as dur
from ((select c.sessionid, c.callSender as caller, c.StartTime, c.EndTime
       from call c
      ) union all
      (select c.sessionid, c.callReceiver, c.StartTime, c.EndTime
       from call c
      )
     ) c
     on s.sessionid = c.sessionid
group by c.sessionid, c.caller
```

From this, you can then aggregate over all sessions.

If the calls periods within a session are not contiguous, then the problem is more challenging.  The best way to solve this problem depends on the database and the functions available in the database.

Comment: First let me thank you, but if i could pester you for some clarifying questions that would be great.

1. c.sessionid should really be call.session id? and s.sessionid be session.sessionid

2. c.caller what should that be I don't have that as a field
3. when you use the phrase

        from call c
what do you mean by that
4. When you mean contiguous, you mean no overlapping phonecall meaning putting someone on hold? If so yes, I specfically entered in data so there is no overlapping by using mutiple dates